# SELECT IN query using returned value as CSV

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the results of a subquery in an IN query to return some results from a table based on some ids in a second table. The structure of Table1 is not important, but Table2 stores information like this:

```
other_ID  | members
1         | .10.,.16.,.86.
2         | .32.,.34.
```

`other_ID` is stored as `INT` while `members` is stored as `TEXT`. I didn't create the table structure, but my understanding is that members is stored in that format since it gets tricky storing variable-length CSVs in columns in a database. Either way, I'm not able to change the table structure.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE
Table1.ID IN (REPLACE((SELECT members FROM Table2 WHERE other_ID = 2), ".", ""));
```

Try as I might, the query only ever returns values from the first value in the members column (i.e. 32). If I try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID IN (32,34);
```

The results are returned successfully.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you put replace inside the select fields? like     `select replace(members,".","")`

Comment: Hi sanjun, I started my query that way initially but it produced exactly the same results, so I figured I'd drop the SELECT statement as it didn't seem required.

Comment: are you getting all results without replace function?

Comment: Hi sanjun, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If I don't use that replace function, then `SELECT members FROM Table2 WHERE other_ID = 2` returns `.32.,.34.`, which is not useable. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, i just told u this to identify if the Replace function is making this issue

Comment: Hi sanjun, it doesn't look like REPLACE is the cause of the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `REGEXP` here with a join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.members REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', t1.ID, '[[:>:]]')
WHERE
    t2.other_ID = 2;
```

The regex logic used above would compare this members string:

```
.32.,.34.
```

against a regex which looks like this:

```
\b34\b
```

This should work, as the commas/dots surrounding each number in `members` form a word boundary.

Note that the best long term fix here would be to not store your data in unnormalized CSV format.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Could you please explain to me why my query doesn't work? Also, from my (very cursory) inspection, your query takes about 10 times longer to return a result (I suspect because of the JOIN). Is there no way to write my original query not using a JOIN?

Comment: The `WHERE IN` clause needs to be followed by a CSV list of _columns_, not a text CSV list.  My query takes a while because we are invoking a regex engine for each join condition.  To avoid this penalty, consider _normalizing_ your table, and get ID onto a separate row.

Comment: OK great, thanks very much for the explanation Tim.

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE((SELECT members FROM Table2 WHERE other_ID = 2), ".", "")

this will not work because it will take as single number you have to split that string as below.
This worked for me

select * from IS_ACC_ACTIVITY_ERROR_LOGS where ERROR_LOG_ID IN(
select regexp_substr ((SELECT REPLACE(ERROR_DESCRIPTION,'.','') des FROM IS_ACC_ACTIVITY_ERROR_LOGS WHERE ERROR_LOG_ID = 2), '[^,]+', 1, rn) as splited_string
     from dual
     cross
     join (select rownum as rn
             from dual
          connect by level <= 2))

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately your code doesn't use the parameters I've supplied in my original question. Also, I'm using MySQL 5.6 which doesn't support REGEXP_SUBSTR.